# How to input text for each user in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In Instagram clone project, I created comment box for each user, submitting comments works properly but, inputting text shows text for all users. Following is the code required.

Home.js

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState(null)
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(UserContext)

    /* Comment function */
    const makeComment = (text,postId)=>{
        fetch('/comment',{
            method:"put",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
                "Authorization":"Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("jwt")
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                postId,
                text
            })
        }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(result=>{
            console.log(result)
            const newData = data.map(item=>{
              if(item._id==result._id){
                  return {...item,comments: result.comments}
              }else{
                  return item
              }
           })
          setData(newData)
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
  }

return (
    <div className="home" >
    {
        data.map(item => {
            return (
                <div className="card home-card" key={item._id}>
                 <div className="profile-card">
                 
                 /* Profile Image */
                 <img style={{width: '50px', height:'50px', borderRadius:'80px'}} 
                            src={item.postedBy.image} />
                 <span style={{display:'flex', flexWrap:'wrap', width:'85%'}}>
                 
                 /* Profile Link */
                 <h5><Link to={item.postedBy._id !== state._id ? "/profile/"+item.postedBy._id : "/profile" } > {item.postedBy.name} </Link></h5>
                 </span>
                </div>
                
               /* Post Image */
               <div className="card-image">
           <img style={{width: '100%', height:'260px'}} src={item.photo} alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <hr/>
           
           /* Like Button */
           <div className="like-section">
               {   item.likes.includes(state._id) ? 
               <FavoriteIcon className="like-heart" style={{ fontSize: 25 }} onClick={()=>{unlikePost(item._id)}} /> :
               <FavoriteBorderIcon className="unlike-heart" style={{ fontSize: 25 }} onClick={()=>{likePost(item._id)}} /> 
                 }

                 <h6>{item.likes.length}</h6>
                </div>
                <br/>
                 /* Comments Section */
                 <div className="card-content">
                                <h6><b>{item.title}</b></h6>
                                <p>{item.body}</p>
                                {
                                    item.comments.map(record => {
                                        return (
                                        <>    
                                        <h6 key={record._id}><b className="posted-by">{record.postedBy.name}</b>{record.text}</h6>
                                        </>
                                        
                                        )
                                    })
                                }

                      {

                      /* Comment Box  */
                      <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            makeComment(e.target[0].value, item._id)
                            setNewText("")
                       }}>
                                        
                     <input type="text" value={newtext} onChange={onChange} placeholder="add a comment" />
                     <button type="submit" disabled={!newtext}>Post</button>
                                    </form>
                                } 
                                
                                 
                            </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
</div>
);
};

export default Home;
```

When typing comments in particular comment box only that should be focused and display text, but all other comments are displayed

Below is the image reference

[image]

Above image you can see 'Hello' text when typed is displayed in both comment box

[image]

Here you can see 'Hello' text is submitted properly to the that particular id

So, any appropriate solution?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using the same state for each comment boxes.
To overcome this, you need to create as many state as users.
You can do this easily by using an array for comments

```
const [newText, setNewText] = useState([])

data.map((item, index) => (
...
<input value={newText[index]} onChange={(e) => setNewText(replaceByIndex(newText, index, e.target.value))} />
...
)
```

FYI, here's `replaceByIndex` function:

```
const replaceByIndex = (originArray, index, newItem) => 
    originArray.map((item, i) => i === index ? newItem: item)
```

Additional enhancements to your code:

- Performance enhancements: use `useCallback` react hook to define functions in function components.
- Use meaningful naming conventions. It's hard to understand what the data and item means...

Comment: Well that issue is solved, but, error occured as 'TypeError: originArray.map is not a function'

Comment: Did you pass an array to the first argument?

Comment: replaceByIndex([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 4) will return [0, 1, 4, 3, 4]